# getJSON inside another getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm trying to get the IP address and GPS coordinates of the client. Using jQuery, I have this:

```js
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com/", function(data) {
  var locationURL = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" + data.ip;
  $('#IPdiv').html(locationURL);
  $.getJSON(locationURL, function(locationData) {
    $('#GPSdiv').html(locationData.country_name);
    console.log(locationData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='IPdiv'></div>
<div id='GPSdiv'></div>
```

First I'm requesting the users IP address from an external site. Then I use the returned data to create another URL that is called. Sadly, the inner getJSON method isn't being run. Firebug doesn't even show the URL being called. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Problem solved. The Ghostery plugin was blocking freegeoip.net.

Comment: Here it ís working. it shows me my IP, and then my country underneath it. Or does it need to do something else?

Comment: The snippet works for me. I see my ip & country(in a little delay so I guess the second getJson worked as well).

Comment: It's not working for me, either here or in my project. The second URL never gets created. Weird.

Comment: Try expanding it to the `$.ajax` equivalent, and using an `error` callback too.  FWIW, it works fine for me too.

Comment: New discovery, it doesn't work in my Firefox but it does work in Internet Explorer. Is IE now officially better than Firefox?

Comment: It works for me too,with following in response
{"ip":"xx.xx.xx.xx","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India","region_code":"","region_name":"","city":"","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Kolkata","latitude":x,"longitude":x,"metro_code":0}

NOTE:changed certain fields to xx

Comment: This fiddle uses the promise api (only a small variation on what you had) - and works... http://jsfiddle.net/sygjevrn/  what does it give you?

Comment: Does your javascript console show any errors?

Comment: Fixed it, Ghostery was the issue. I'm not sure whether to delete the question, or keep it up so people are reminded that Ghostery blocks some links.

Comment: if you do leave it, post that as the answer rather than as an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The Ghostery plugin was blocking freegeoip.net. What I learned from this experience: Always check if the Ghostery icon shows anything being blocked while working on your site!